# Transform Image from Jquery .animate image into a animated GIF?

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, animated-gif

First of all i have to say this is a strange one:

Client has a image:
http://tinyurl.com/9r4cqcr

I created a .animate canvas of this: http://tinyurl.com/9yqcrkm

How would one make of the .animate canvas a plain animated .GIF.

i know the logic is strange and backwards, but seem interesting enough to see if this is possible, cheers everyone for shooting. Iwan

Comment: +1 Awesome work on waving the flag..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help:

http://antimatter15.com/wp/2010/07/javascript-to-animated-gif/

Its pretty much full fledged GIF encoder in JS! Since the built-in `toDataURL()` exports only a single frame (the frame at the point of calling the function)

Comment: still must be doing something wrong as i have tried to implement this, but looks very ugly, does not stay onscreen has a blackbackground rather than being transparent., might not be the right solution for my problem, i think i just need to create a animated gif by hand.

Comment: yes, but maybe this can make it a little easy for you.. If you can step through the animation frame by frame and save out each frame as a PNG or so via code.. You can later stitch these frames together easily I guess..

Comment: yeah that was my plan too, however client has changed their mind and so i won't have to lookk any further cheers for this help with this weird topic.